# "If" statement in React Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-context

How can I use "if" statement in Context.Consumer? I need to check if **context.state.showLoginBox** is true, then show the div below.

```
class LogInBox extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <MyContext.Consumer>
                {(context) => (// context.state.showLoginBox ? => show div below
                    <div className="logInBoxWrapper" id="logInBoxId">
                        <div className="logInBox">
                            <h3>Войти</h3>

                            <form method="">
                                <input name="email" placeholder="Электронная почта" required/>
                                <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Пароль" required/>
                                <button type="submit">Войти</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </MyContext.Consumer>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: change `? =>` with `&&`, and if you want to use it as `if/else` use `?:` operator

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `if statement` in context callback if you use explicit return like

```
class LogInBox extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <MyContext.Consumer>
                {(context) => {

               if(context.state.showLoginBox)  {
                   return <div className="logInBoxWrapper" id="logInBoxId">
                        <div className="logInBox">
                            <h3>Войти</h3>

                            <form method="">
                                <input name="email" placeholder="Электронная почта" required/>
                                <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Пароль" required/>
                                <button type="submit">Войти</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  }
                  return null;
                }}
            </MyContext.Consumer>
        );
    }
}
```

otherwise with implicit return you can use ternary operators

```
class LogInBox extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <MyContext.Consumer>
                {(context) => context.state.showLoginBox ?  <div className="logInBoxWrapper" id="logInBoxId">
                        <div className="logInBox">
                            <h3>Войти</h3>

                            <form method="">
                                <input name="email" placeholder="Электронная почта" required/>
                                <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Пароль" required/>
                                <button type="submit">Войти</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </MyContext.Consumer> : null
    }
}
```